# How can I keep leading zeros when concatenating two numbers together in a query?

Tags: sql, ms-access, ms-access-2007

## Question

How can I keep leading zeros when concatenating two numbers together in an Access query?

## Table

```
FileYear | FileIteration
------------------------ 
14       | 0001
14       | 0002
14       | 0003
14       | 0004
```

(`FileIteration` has a "0000" format, but is still stored as integer)

## Query

```
SELECT MAX(FileYear & FileIteration)
FROM FileNumber
WHERE FileYear=Format(Date(),"yy");
```

## Current (wrong) output

> 144

It doesn't keep leading zeros.

## Desired output

> 140004

I want it to keep leading zeros.

Comment: What are the data types for FileIteration and FileYear

Comment: @rontornambe FilteIteration is an integer (as stated in question), FileYear comes from `Format(Date(),"yy")`. (`INSERT`ed before) Works as an integer to (as far as I know)

Comment: If FileInteration is an Integer, how do you show values of 0004? Wouldn't the leading zeros be automatically truncated?

Comment: @rontornambe [Nope](http://i.stack.imgur.com/ycxPD.png). Adding a format of "0000" forces it to have four numbers. ("*Numérique*" = "Number")

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using the `Format` function is my opinion the "correct" way to do it although there are many ways to achieve what you want in this case.

The output of `Format()` will be a string

```
SELECT MAX(FileYear & Format(FileIteration,"0000"))
FROM FileNumber
WHERE FileYear=Format(Date(),"yy");
```

Comment: I like that approach and agree that it's better (more general) than what I suggested.

Comment: Thanks, I prefer this approach as if ever the FileIteration goes higher than 9999 then it wont add "1" to the year.

Answer (score 1):

If it's always a 4-digit number, you can simply do this:

```
Fileyear * 10000 + FileIteration
```

If the number of digits is dynamic, let's assume it's in the column NoOfDigits:

```
Fileyear * 10 ^ NoOfDigits + FileIteration
```

Answer (score 1):

One possible Access SQL statement for your query, assuming for a 4-digit FileIteration is:

```
SELECT Max(([FileYear]*1000)+[FileIteration]) AS Answer
FROM FileNumber
WHERE ((([FileYear])=Format(Date(),"yy")));
```

Answer (score -1):

Convert them to strings before concatenating:

```
CStr(Fileyear) & CStr(FileIteration)
```

Comment: In MS Access, "CStr(Fileyear) & CStr(FileIteration)" will actually yield 141, 142, 143, 144 for the example in question. The leading zeros are not preserved. Kind of an odd behavior, but that's how it works. At least in Access 2010, which is what I just used to run a test.

Comment: This is incorrect in the MS Access flavor of SQL.  I confirmed it in Access 2007

Comment: It really depends on what data types FileYear and FileIteration are. Since it is not clear from the question, this answer works just fine if FileIteration is Text. And how would you input 0004 if it is numeric?

Comment: @rontornambe I did state clearly that `FileIteration`was stored as an integer in my question..